# How can I restart countdown in javascript using button

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem I don't know how can I restart the countdown in **javascript** using button and the countdown is in the localstorage.
How can I restart the countdown using button and it will be not restart if the countdown is not finished. Thank you .

```js
var hoursleft = 0;
var minutesleft = 35;
var secondsleft = 0;
var finishedtext = "Countdown finished!";
var end;
if (localStorage.getItem("end")) {
  end = new Date(localStorage.getItem("end"));
} else {
  end = new Date();
  end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + minutesleft);
  end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds() + secondsleft);
}
var counter = function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var diff = end - now;
  diff = new Date(diff);
  var sec = diff.getSeconds();
  var min = diff.getMinutes();
  if (min < 10) {
    min = "0" + min;
  }
  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }
  if (now >= end) {
    clearTimeout(interval);
    localStorage.setItem("end", null)
    document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = finishedtext;
  } else {
    var value = min + ":" + sec;
    localStorage.setItem("end", end);
    document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="divCounter"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what appears to be the problem with your attempt?

Comment: I try something but the countdown didnt restart and it shown as Nan:Nan please help me

Comment: Maybe this is something you would be interested in using [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/jsr42wpd/) The interval and storage is removed when the counter expires.

Comment: How can apply in the button? Because its automatic create a button

Comment: What do you mean how can you apply the button? You said you only wanted the button to work when the time expires.

Comment: If you want the button to be on the page all the time but only enable it when the counter has expired you can always use this method [**Second JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/tgba9esn/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your Time my problem is solved now